# Cascade Merge not working fine

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have created this code:

```
Sale sale = new Sale();
sale = saleService.create(sale);

Company company = new Company("companyName");

Vendor vendor = new Vendor("name", company);

sale.setVendor(vendor);

try {
        sale = saleService.update(sale);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("");
    }

Product product = new Product("name", company);
sale.setProduct(product);

try {
        sale = saleService.update(sale);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("");
    }
```

Also, sale is in cascade with vendor:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, 
 targetEntity = Vendor.class)
private Vendor vendor;
```

and Vendor and Product with Company:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, 
 targetEntity = Company.class)
private Company company;
```

The saleService has this code:

```
@Transactional
public Sale create(Sale entity) {
    Sale created = entity;
    saleRepository.saveAndFlush(created);
    return created;
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = EntityNotFoundException.class)
public Calibration update(Calibration entity) throws EntityNotFoundException {

   if (!calibrationRepository.exists(entity.getId())) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    }


    return calibrationRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
}
```

It's also annoted as `@Service`. The repository is an Interface that implements `JpaRepository<Sale, Long>`.

I'm getting an Error saying that the `name` property of Company is duplicated, and it must not be. It's clear to me that the code is trying to created another company in database. How to just merge or use the already created one?

Thanks!

Comment: You should not be creating a new instance, and instead read the instance you want to update from the context and use that instance for your changes.

Comment: New instance of what?

Comment: Ok, I got it...I should get the company again from the database. Put it as answer and I'll set it as the correct one.